# Cauchy-Riemann equations not satisfied for $\log z$ when $v(x,y)$ is defined via $\arccos$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

If we define, for $z:=x+yi$, where $z,y \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\log z = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)= \ln(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+i\underbrace{\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)}_\Theta$ with some branch, say, $-\pi<\Theta<\pi$. Now, of course, we could have defined $v(x,y)=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$, and the Cauchy-Riemann equations would be satisfied for this function. However, even though it should be equivalent to define $v(x,y)$ via $\arccos$, we get these partial derivatives for $v(x,y)$:
$$v_x=-\frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)|y|}, v_y=\frac{xy}{|y|(x^2+y^2)}$$

The difference with the partial derivatives of $v$ defined via $\arctan$ is the presence of the absolute value of $y$, which prevents $y$ from cancelling out from the numerator and the denominator of the two derivatives.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the definition is wrong when $y < 0$.

EDIT: The definition with arctan is also wrong for $x < 0$, but there the wrong definition (off by a constant when it's wrong) is still holomorphic.  The definition with arccos has the wrong sign of $v$ when it's wrong.

Comment: But why does the definition work if $v(x,y)=\arctan(\frac{y}{x})$?